# SSRS Variance on Matrix Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to generate a weekly SSRS report to show **WTD**, **MTD** and **YTD** values compared to the prior period.

I have successfully built my report using the following query:

```
WITH CTE
 AS (
 SELECT *,
        ReportPeriod = 'Current WTD',
        ColumnOrder = 1
 FROM SALES_FLASH_DAILY
 WHERE CompletedDate BETWEEN @CurrentWeekStart AND @Today
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *,
        ReportPeriod = 'Prior WTD',
        ColumnOrder = 2
 FROM SALES_FLASH_DAILY
 WHERE CompletedDate BETWEEN @PrevWeekStart AND @DayinPrevWeek
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *,
        ReportPeriod = 'Current MTD',
        ColumnOrder = 3
 FROM SALES_FLASH_DAILY
 WHERE CompletedDate BETWEEN @CurrentMonthStart AND @Today
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *,
        ReportPeriod = 'Prior MTD',
        ColumnOrder = 4
 FROM SALES_FLASH_DAILY
 WHERE CompletedDate BETWEEN @PrevMonthStart AND @DayinPrevMonth
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *,
        ReportPeriod = 'Current YTD',
        ColumnOrder = 5
 FROM SALES_FLASH_DAILY
 WHERE CompletedDate BETWEEN @CurrentYearStart AND @Today
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *,
        ReportPeriod = 'Prior YTD',
        ColumnOrder = 6
 FROM SALES_FLASH_DAILY
 WHERE CompletedDate BETWEEN @PrevYearStart AND @DayinPrevYear)

 SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

However, I now want to add columns to capture the variance for each period at the end of the Matrix.

This is a sample of the data set I am working with:

[image: Sample Data]

This is the report Structure (a snippet of part of the report):

[image: Report Body]

This is the output I am trying to create:

[image: Output]

Does anyone know how this can be done? Can it dynamically be done within SSRS or do I need to perform self joins to have ReportPeriodSales as a column?

Thank you.

Comment: Post some sample data and expected result would really help.

Comment: @kc2018 I have added data and anticipated report output. Thank you.

Comment: Seems it can be done within SSRS. Your query already created all the raw data required for the calculation.

Comment: How can I specify which columns generated by the matrix to use for my variance calculations? Is there a way to specify "Value for Current WTD" - "Value for Prior WTD"?

Comment: This may help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/be3e6d81-cd79-44cf-98e8-b23ef13afa36/how-to-add-calculated-column-from-dynamic-columns-to-a-matrix?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @choloboy You should be able to reference those fields in the data set and just take the difference.

Comment: Do you know why such a formula would cause the report rendering to take forever? From 10 seconds to 10 minutes (literally)?